# Apache - Mountain Lion - How to modify httpd.conf

Tags: apache, osx-lion, httpd.conf

I'm trying to configure the preinstalled Apache server in Mountain Lion.

I need to modify the httpd.conf file. By CLI I have no problems, but, I want to do it with TextEdit or another editor.

The problem is:
I can't open as root a file in the Finder, so, I changed the permission on this file to read and write, but isn't enough. I can only create a Duplicate when I save the changes.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few non-command-line-editors that, unlike TextEdit, CAN open as root. I use [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) for example.

Comment: So it's a TextEdit's problem.. I tried with Sublime Text and it works fine!